# How can I apply LR with non-linear features?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, prediction, nonlinear-regression

My training data looks like this:

`win   gender     age     country  ...
1        F       20         US    ...
1        M       21         CA    ...
0        M       22         CA    ...
0        M       20         CN    ...`

Now I want to apply `Logistic Regression` to predict the win rate of a specified person, I understand the feature `age`, but for `country` and `gender`, I don't  think they fit for my need (I think only linear features should be used), is there anyway to use them in LR(or other simple algorithms) ?

Comment: There's no reason you can't use categorical features in logistic regression and any standard statistical software should handle it. I also think you are confusing the terms linear and continuous

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Let's say that your model is:
$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{c_age}+\beta_2 \text{female}+ \beta_3\text{country}+\varepsilon$$
where $\text{c_age}$ is $\text{age}-mean(\text{age})$ and $\text{country}$ is a factor, and you get:

```
Intercept    0.4
c_age        0.3
female      -1.1
countryCA    0.5
countryCN   -1.0
...
```

In a logistic model
$$P(y=1\mid\mathbf{X})=\text{logit}^{-1}(\mathbf{X\beta})=\frac{1}{1+\exp(-\mathbf{X\beta})}$$
so:
$$\begin{align} P(\text{win}=1\mid mean(\text{age}), \text{male}, \text{US})&=\text{logit}^{-1}(0.4)\approx 0.60\\
P(\text{win}=1\mid mean(\text{age}), \text{female}, \text{CA})&=\text{logit}^{-1}(0.4-1.1+0.5)\approx 0.45 \\
P(\text{win}=1\mid mean(\text{age}), \text{female}, \text{CN})&=\text{logit}^{-1}(0.4-1.1-1.0)\approx 0.15 \\
P(\text{win}=1\mid mean(\text{age}), \text{male}, \text{CN})&=\text{logit}^{-1}(0.4-1.0)\approx 0.35 \end{align}$$
etc.

Comment: Cool, make sense to me.